# jquery animation. Border problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have this situation: http://jsfiddle.net/pedroR/wF2P5/2/

When the mouse is hover each columns its animate with a change of width. That's ok. The problem is that the border-left that initially are bigger, it becomes in the same height as the columns. But I don't want that, I want that the border stays in the same size. I already tried with images but with no success.

Any Ideas?? What I'm doing wrong and how should I solve this problem??

Thanks

Comment: i honestly have tried hard but i can really not figure out what that problem is or what you are trying to do can you please describe more specifically with different words what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: When the mouse passes over each column, it increases its width, as I wanted. But the white border-left also suffers from this animation, so it will have a height equal to the column. What  I wanted to keep the original height of the border-left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `.animate()` adds `overflow: hidden` while the animation is running.

One way to fix this without a lot of reworking is to set `.css('overflow','visible')` when you call `.animate()`, for example:

```
$this.stop().animate({'width':'100px'},500).css('overflow', 'visible');
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/wF2P5/4/

Answer (score 1):

During the `animate` call `overflow: hidden` is added to the elements, which hides the extended borders. After the animate call, the overflow is never reset.

You could either manually call `css('overflow', 'auto')` after the animation has completed, or structure your content in a different way which doesn't involve relative positioning.